# Having trouble implementing try and except in PDFminer

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except, pdfminer

I have a script that runs through an entire directory and pulls every PDF and extracts the text and finds key words in each PDF. It seems to work fine with a handful of PDF files but, whenever it encounters a PDF with some issue, the script breaks.

I implemented a try and except block in the function to avoid these issues but it doesn't seem to work as the script just continuously runs. I am new to all of this, especially, using try and except blocks. How fix my script to use try and except blocks so that the script will process only the good PDF's and ignore all the bad ones without breaking the script?

```
p = Path("C:/Users/Hugo Caldeira/Desktop")
inp = r"((?<=|^)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}(?=|$))"

file_dict = {
        "name": [],
        "created": [],
        "modified":[],
        'path':[],
        'content':[],
        'keyword':[]
}

files = list(p.rglob('*pdf'))

def pdfparser(file):
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    #Create a PDF interpreter object.
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    #Process each page contained in the document.

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        data =  retstr.getvalue()

    return(data)


def pdfs(files):
        for name in files:
                while True:
                        try:
                                IP_list = (pdfparser(name))
                        except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
                                print('got error')
                        keyword = re.findall(inp,IP_list)
                        #print(ip_test)
                        file_dict['keyword'].append(keyword)
                        file_dict['name'].append(name.name[0:])
                        file_dict['created'].append(time.ctime(name.stat().st_ctime))
                        file_dict['modified'].append(time.ctime(name.stat().st_mtime))
                        file_dict['path'].append(name)
                        file_dict["content"].append(IP_list)
                        #print(file_dict)
        return(file_dict)
pdfs(files)


print(pdfparser(p))

def to_xlsx():
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file_dict)
    df.head()
    df.to_excel("pdftest.xlsx")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    to_xlsx()
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, the code after your try/except will fail, because you are referring to a name bound in the try section. Even if not, there's no way out of your while loop. Instead:

```py
for name in files:
    try:
        IP_list = (pdfparser(name))
        keyword = re.findall(inp,IP_list)
        ... # Etc, etc.
    except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):
        print("Error processing {}".format(name))
```